# write lists to pandas dataframe to csv, read dataframe from csv and convert to lists again without having strings

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, csv

Originally I had a list of list and each list contains tuples of strings (from some computations). I want to save them for later, so I don't have to do all the computations again and just read the csv.

```
 L = [l1,l2,...]
 l1 = [('a','b'), ('c','d'),...]
 l2 = [('e','f'), ('g','h'),...]...
```

I converted it to a pandas data frame:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame(L)
 df.to_csv('MyLists.csv', sep=";")
```

So each list l is saved as a row in the csv.
Some time later I want to use the list saved in the csv again.
So I imported pandas again and did:

```
readdf = pd.read_csv('MyLists.csv', delimiter = ";")
newList = readdf.values.tolist()
```

The problem is that every tuple is a string itself now, i.e. every list in newList looks as follows:

```
l1 = ['('a','b')', '('c', 'd')',...]
```

When I look at the csv with a text editor, it looks correct, somehow like:

```
('a','b');('c','d');...
```

I tried to read it directly with:

```
import csv

newList = []
with open('MyLists.csv') as f:    
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        newList.append(row)
```

But the problem is the same.
So how can I get rid of the extra " ' "?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need convert `string`s to `tuples`, because data in `csv` are `string`s:

```
import ast

l1 = [('a','b'), ('c','d')]
l2 = [('e','f'), ('g','h')]
L = [l1,l2]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
        0       1
0  (a, b)  (c, d)
1  (e, f)  (g, h)

df.to_csv('MyLists.csv', sep=";")

readdf = pd.read_csv('MyLists.csv', delimiter = ";", index_col=0)
newList = readdf.applymap(ast.literal_eval).values.tolist()
print (newList)
[[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')], [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]]
```

But I think better is use pickle for save your data - use [`to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) / [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html):

```
df.to_pickle('MyLists.pkl')
```